# Using older Python 2.x while having both Python 2.x and 3.x installed on Windows

Tags: python, windows

I'm new to python. I've installed both Python 3.2.2 for x64 and Python 2.7 for x86 on my 64-bit windows machine. I've got some python code that are coded for python 2.x versions. But every time I try to run them by double clicking it is interpreted by python 3.x.

How do I force them to use python version 2.7, may be using some directives or using a BATCH script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going forward, the solution is to upgrade Python 3.2 to 3.3 or later and use the [Python Launcher for Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows).

At the top of each Python 3 program, include the following line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

At the top of each Python 2 program, include the following line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
```

The `#!` part, called a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)), indicates to Python Launcher which version of Python is desired. (It also indicates to UNIX that a program should be run with a particular interpreter instead of the shell.) The `/usr/bin/env` part helps locate the Python interpreter on your `PATH` when you run a program on UNIX. If you don't plan on using anything but Windows, you can leave it out:

```
#! python3

[or]

#! python2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could, e.g., associate the file extension `.py2` with Python 2.7 and rename the main file (assuming you regard Python 3.2 as your default version).

Answer (score 0):

open a command line window, and use `"c:\python27\python.exe" yourscript.py` (or whatever path your python 2.7 appears to be installed in).

of course, you can put that line into a batch file and execute the batch.

also, you can put a shortcut to `c:\python27\python.exe` on your desktop and drop your script onto that shortcut every time you want to run it.

Answer (score -1):

try editing `PATH` environment variable, use python 2.7 path and delete python 3.2.2

Comment: Can't delete python 3.2.2 from PATH. It's required for other software.